# Styling ListPopupWindow widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-styles

I have an android application where I create a ListPopupWindow when a user click on a view element. The ListPopupWindow widget is created using the default theme which is holo black.

```
 final ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ChoiceListItem>(context,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, choices);
 final ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(context);
 // ...   
 listPopupWindow.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How could I change ListPopupWindow colors to use for example holo light or even custom color for text, item background and divider between items ?

Preferably, I'm looking for a solution that uses XML files (i.e. how should I edit my themes and styles files).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define a [listPopupWindowStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listPopupWindowStyle) for your App's theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
    <item name="android:listPopupWindowStyle">@style/MyListPopupWindow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyListPopupWindow">
    <!-- attributes you want go here -->
</style>
```

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested. MyListPopupWindow contains '<item name="android:popupBackground">#fff</item>' and the style AppTheme is used in the android:theme of my AndroidManifest.xml. Unfortunately, this definition has no effect on the popup that is drawn.

Comment: I succeeded to make it work. First, I applied the style MyListPopWindow to my ListPopWindow by using the constructor with four arguments, the last being the resource id of MyListPopupWindow. Second, I used `<item name="android:popupBackground">#xxxxxx</item>` to change background color.

Answer (score 2):

Another and, I think, very simple way is to create drawable with color and to set it as a background.

bg_popup_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/bg_work_item_menu"/>
</selector>
```

and

```
listPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(
     context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_popup_menu));
```

Hope it'll be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

For background you can use colorBackground:

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/your_color</item>
```